# Codeigniter Joining table and displaying name instead of id

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, join

Table

```
-------------------------------
table 1 (customer) : id , name
table 2 (transaction): receiver(int), seller(int)
---------------------------------------------------
```

How do I display table 2 (both) receiver and seller as name based on the customers id?

---

I tried:

```
    $this->db->select('transactions.*');


    $this->db->select("customer.id AS c_id");
    $this->db->select("customer.name AS c_name");
    $this->db->from("customer"); //edited
    $this->db->join('transactions', 'customer.id = transactions.receiver');
    $this->db->join('transactions', 'customer.id = transactions.sender = customer.id');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
```

But it give me error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax /check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'JOIN '

---

I checked other similar questions but still couldn't figure it out.

Comment: `from()` is missing ?

Comment: Use `get_compiled_select()` to get the query so you can var_dump or echo it.. i think @MKhalidJunaid is right `$this->db->from('transactions')` looks to be missing.

Comment: i added from() and it seem that syntax is fixed.However it said not unique table . Am i selecting it wrong?? And how do i call to display the name in view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For join same table for multiple column query like this

```
$this->db->select('transaction.*,tbl_receiver.name as receiver_name,tbl_sender.name as sender_name');
$this->db->join('customer as tbl_receiver','tbl_receiver.id=transaction.receiver');
$this->db->join('customer as tbl_sender','tbl_sender.id=transaction.sender');
return $this->db->get('transaction')->result_array();
```